# 127.0.0.1:9912 port cause decrease speed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

my Host speed became law, and the host support said the port 9912 is not active from us and your code tries to connect to it and it causes your site to be slow, I searched it and find this port in my codes
 how should I disable this port from my codes?

config.php

```
    <?php

return [
    /*
     * The host to use when listening for debug server connections.
     */
    'host' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9912',
];
```

and  var-dump-server file:

```
function includeIfExists(string $file): bool
{
    return file_exists($file) && include $file;
}

if (
    !includeIfExists(__DIR__ . '/../../../../autoload.php') &&
    !includeIfExists(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php') &&
    !includeIfExists(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php')
) {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'Install dependencies using Composer.'.PHP_EOL);
    exit(1);
}

if (!class_exists(Application::class)) {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'You need the "symfony/console" component in order to run the VarDumper server.'.PHP_EOL);
    exit(1);
}

$input = new ArgvInput();
$output = new ConsoleOutput();
$defaultHost = '127.0.0.1:9912';
$host = $input->getParameterOption(['--host'], $_SERVER['VAR_DUMPER_SERVER'] ?? $defaultHost, true);
$logger = interface_exists(LoggerInterface::class) ? new ConsoleLogger($output->getErrorOutput()) : null;

$app = new Application();

$app->getDefinition()->addOption(
    new InputOption('--host', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The address the server should listen to', $defaultHost)
);

$app->add($command = new ServerDumpCommand(new DumpServer($host, $logger)))
    ->getApplication()
    ->setDefaultCommand($command->getName(), true)
    ->run($input, $output)
;
```